Maximize and Minimize UIViewControler on Top of other apps swift IOS
Is there a way to make an application widget like UIView appears all the time, even on the home screen. I want to make a floating view which will appear on top of all the apps. I am working on a video calling application (VOIP Call) and want to maximize and minimize the calling screen during call like that in Microsoft teams app in IOS. Given below the screenshot of MS teams app

Any awesome ideas?

You can use PIP mode from the av framework

can you share any example? i Tried but not working

https://forasoft.medium.com/picture-in-picture-mode-on-ios-implementation-and-peculiarities-27d5e327b265
